# Need to populate Date of Birth field using Ampscript, but its populating current date not populating Date of Birth from my DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am using the below script to populate Date of birth:

```
%%[
var @emailaddress
var @data
var @dtenvio, @year, @month, @day

SET @dtenvio = iif(empty(QueryParameter("Date_Of_Birth")),Now(),QueryParameter("Date_Of_Birth"))
set @data = FormatDate(@dtenvio, "YYYY-MM-DD")
set @year = DatePart(@data,"Y")
set @month = DatePart(@data,"M")
set @day = DatePart(@data,"D")
Set @emailaddress = [Email Address] 
Set @emailaddress = Lookup("Master Data Extension","Email Address","Email Address",@emailaddress)
]%%

@dtenvio: %%=v(@dtenvio)=%%
@data: %%=v(@data)=%%
@year: %%=v(@year)=%%
@month: %%=v(@month)=%%
@day: %%=v(@day)=%%

Output:
?email=rs@km.com&dateformat=2020-04-21&year=2020&month=04&day=21&rs=4/21/2020%203:47:27%20PM

But the birthday is:2/29/1985
```

Answer (score 1):

the correct code is:

```
%%[
var @emailaddress
var @data
var @dtenvio, @year, @month, @day

SET @dtenvio = AttributeValue("Date_Of_Birth")
set @data = FormatDate(@dtenvio, "YYYY-MM-DD")
set @year = DatePart(@data,"Y")
set @month = DatePart(@data,"M")
set @day = DatePart(@data,"D")
Set @emailaddress = [Email Address] 
Set @emailaddress = Lookup("Master Data Extension","Email Address","Email Address",@emailaddress)
]%%

@dtenvio: %%=v(@dtenvio)=%%
@data: %%=v(@data)=%%
@year: %%=v(@year)=%%
@month: %%=v(@month)=%%
@day: %%=v(@day)=%%
```